# Error generate executable in Python. (py2exe)

Tags: python, anaconda, py2exe, win32com

I am working with `Py2exe` to generate an executable in Python(anaconda 3) and it gives me this error.

running py2exe

```
Error: Namespace packages not yet supported: Skipping package 'win32com.gen_py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 32, in <module>
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

...

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 261, in _gcd_import
    name = self._resolve_name(name, package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 213, in _resolve_name
    raise ValueError('attempted relative import beyond top-level package')
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191922/py2exe-error-namespace-packages-not-yet-supported-skipping-package-snowflake

This question might help you

Comment: thanks @J0hn I already solved. I used Pyinstaller